# BottomSheet hides when outside content changes

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a viewgroup with BottomSheetBehaviour from MaterialComponents (the sheet content is clickable, hidable)

The layout included in parent (CooridnatorLayout)

```
<include
   android:id="@+id/filters_sheet"
   layout="@layout/station_filters"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
   app:behavior_hideable="true"
   app:behavior_peekHeight="48dp"
   app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"
   app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
```

The content of sheet has 2 switch components (for filtering the list behind sheet)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/filter_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/filters_sheet_background"
    android:elevation="@dimen/small_space">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/station_filter_only_available"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
        android:padding="@dimen/space"
        android:text="@string/station_filter_only_available" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/station_filter_with_partners"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/space"
        android:text="@string/station_filter_with_partners"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now each time I click on  any filter switch, the list is updated (by triggering new value on live data) but the sheet disappears, but internal state of BottomSheetBehaviour is still STATE_EXPANDED.

Is this a bug in library (com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0) or I'm missing something?

Thanks

```
station_filter_only_available.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
   if (parentViewModel.stationFilters.value != null) {
       parentViewModel.stationFilters.value = parentViewModel.stationFilters.value!!.copy(onlyAvailable = isChecked)
   }
}
```